# How to avoid multiple $(document).ready()

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, code-organization

I work on a ASP.NET application using Jquery. Jquery is really powerfull and I use a lot of it.
In my master page I include all libraries I use and a js file who contain the jquery code available for all the application (interface interactions). In this js File (Main.js) I make some things so I use the `$(document).ready( ... etc .. )`

But in some pages, who are more complex I need to use some other jquery code.. So I add some head Content with other script tag.. And this the problem, I have to add the `$(document).ready()` instruction again.

There is a lot of problems with my asp controls with this way to do, the autopostback controls doesn't do their autopostback.. I think this is a problem with the multiple `$(document).ready()` declaration because when I remove the second one(in the page not in the master page) the controls are working.

So how can I do to add some javascript code in a specific page without multiple `$(document).ready()` declaration. (I don't want to embed all the jquery code in all pages).

I hope I'm clear enough, thanks for responses

Edit here is code

Master page part

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">


<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Styles/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="/js/Menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/iphone-style-checkboxes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src="/js/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>      
    <script src="/js/Main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                   

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>
Some content....

</body>
</html>
```

Main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

/// <reference path="jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js" />

//There is a lot of content here......
```

});

And A page

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dep.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dep" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeadContent1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<link href="../../Styles/nyroModal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../js/jquery.nyroModal.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#tbxDateDebut').datepicker();
        $('#tbxDateFin').datepicker();

        $('.nyroModal').nyroModal();
    });

</script>


</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

//Here comes the controls... (lot of code)       


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post some more of the code? My guess is that there is a parenthesis or something like that missing, since multiple $(document).ready shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Multiple `$(document).ready()` shouldn't be an issue, are they performing some dependent changes coz the order of execution is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //There is a lot of content here......
  if ($.pageReady) $.pageReady($);
});
```

page.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $.pageReady = function() {
    // fired on DOM ready
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, to be sure to understand.. what $.pageready means ? Do you have some link to documentation on this trick for me?

Comment: @bAN pageReady is just a variable your going to make. It's a global variable, Your just storing it on `$` rather then `window`. You may want a more unique name in case it clashes with a jQuery plugin though

Comment: wow, this is just brilliant!

I have used it in order to guarantee that an asynchronous method could be called in the master page's $(document).ready() function while ensuring that the slave page .ready() function would be called only on completion

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question:

> But in some pages, who are more complex I need to use some other jquery code.. So I add some head Content with other script tag.. And this the problem, I have to add the $(document).ready() instruction again.
>
> "But in some pages..."

Unfortunately you have to add a reference for every js file that refers to uncommon elements. That is if you have page 1 with a `<div id="element1">` and another page (page 2) with `<div id="element676">` you would not want to include all in the Jquery handling into Main.js . In fact that would give an error if you had not yet seen page 2.

Damn you guys are quick.... as I was writing @Raynos gave the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

well an alternative is to move all of you jquery document ready to the bottom of your page

```
<body>
... here goes your other html ....

<script>

//$(document).ready(function(){//this is not needed
   ... here goes the first ready...
//});//this is not needed
//$(document).ready(function(){//this is not needed
   ... here goes the second ready ... and so on...
//});//this is not needed
</script>

</body>
```

So in effect you are using document.ready when all other elements are ready :) PS

Comment: This can't be correct because the assumption is that the JQUERY javascript is short. If it is of any considerable length, doing it this way will negatively impact the time your page will load. That's why there is a seperation of duties between HTML and javascript on modern websites. The js files get served independently, and in parallel making page loading quick.

Comment: I dont think DOMReady and button of page are identical.

Comment: each element is loaded one by one, and <script> is just another element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to think that there's something at work here other than your multiple `$(document).ready()` calls. AFAIK, multiple calls against `$(document).ready()` (and even bubbled-up versions, like `$('#someid').ready()`) shouldn't cause issues as they are all aggregated together silently by jQuery for you.

I'd double-check my syntax for starters, and make sure that all your blocks are properly encapsulated, all statements end with a `;`, and all that jazz.